# Can we say "I got starving"?

Tags: adjectives

I know we can say "I got hungry/tired/scared/etc." meaning "I became hungry/tired/scared".
I was wondering if the following sentence sounds as natural:
"I got starving while I was passing by that pizza place"
I have a feeling that it sounds a bit uncommon. Am I right?

Comment: "got starving" is unnatural in AmE.

Comment: We use _starving_ colloquially to mean 'very hungry' rather than 'dying for lack of food', but we don't normally speak of 'getting hungry/starving' suddenly as a result of smelling food.  It would be more natural to say "I suddenly felt hungry" or "I realised how hungry I was".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you're right. While we might use "I am hungry" and "I got hungry" in parallel, I can't think of an "-ing" word for which we would use "I got." I guess that's because these "-ing words" are in "sort of adjectives" and "sort of verbs." If I say "I am walking," then I'm clearly using a present progressive verb. If I say "I am starving," then I'm usually using it in a way that simply describes my state rather than my actions—I'm using it the same as "I am hungry." (Unless I literally mean that I'm dying of malnutrition!) And I guess that's why these "I am ___-ing" constructions don't work with "I became" even when they're usually used in an adjectival role, because they're showing their present-progressive-verb roots, and you don't "become doing something."

Comment: I can think of two "-ing" word for which I would use "I got": *I got moving*, *I got going*.  These seem to use *got* to mean *started*, rather than *became*, and in such usage resemble the construction, *I got **to** thinking*.  I wonder why *moving* and *doing* don't require the *to*.

Comment: @Juhasz Yes, I was trying to think of something like that and could not. Good for you! :) Yes, there get means start.

Comment: @Juhasz Yeah, right after posting I thought of "get cracking." So we have several idiomatic constructions that all seem to be about initiating activity, and as you say, I think we can dismiss them as a different usage of "get," a contraction of "get to."

Answer (score 2):

**to be starving** in colloquial English means to be very hungry.
It's used in BrE and AmE. There is also: to be famished, which also means very hungry, which is not particularly colloquial but is very idiomatic.

**I realized that I was starving** when we passed the pizza place.

**I guess Little Johnny had not had breakfast and was starving when he stuffed down that huge sandwich**.

That said, get starving is not accurate. Get tired, get thirsty, get hungry, are all standard.

*get* in those means to **become,** and you can't "become starving".